# Stop Reloading Fragment after Back Pressed

Tags: android, fragment, android-architecture-navigation

I use navigation component for navigating between my fragments. My app is simple. It has two fragmentsm the first one is list of items and the second one shows details of that Item. When user click on an item, I call

```
    view.findNavController()
     .navigate(R.id.action_photosFragment_to_photoDetailsFragment, bundle)
```

but problem is when I press back button, the first fragment reloads and make a network call again.

```
 override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    photosViewModel.getPhotos()
    photosViewModel.photosLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, photosObserver)
    photosViewModel.loadingLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, loadingObserver)
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
}
```

this block of code calls again! How can I stop reloading?

Answer (score 0):

Use `onCreate()` in your fragment to call the network:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    photosViewModel.getPhotos()
 }
```